# Add existing ExpressRoute to existing Azure Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, express-router

I created a Azure Fabric Cluster without ExpressRoute without any gateway. Created from Azure portal with all default options. Now, my fabric cluster service is not able to access to onprem servers. I understand I need to setup a ExpressRoute for that. We already have an express route created for another fabric cluster.

Can I reuse the same existing expressroute? How do I update my fabric cluster with the existing ExpressRoute in use by other fabric cluster?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your Service fabric to communicate with your on prem you should be able to simply take the properties of the Vnet that it is associated with and from there update the Vnet properties so it is connected to your express route. So you are not configuring the service fabric settings per say but rather the Vnet settings associated with your service fabric.